# I want change status of requests in my list to either accepted or rejected in MVC

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Edit: The function works, the status changes to Y but it gives me a NullReference Exception: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Long story short: I want to add 2 buttons, Accept/Reject. Accept changes the Status to "Y" when clicked, Rejected changes it to "N".

I have a MVC project that lists all the data from DB that is consumed from a web API that I created. I have two ActionLinks Accept/Reject which I want to use to change the property Status to either Y or N for accept/reject for each row.

One of my properties in my Model class:

```
public string Status { get; set; };
```

I have this method :

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    SubscriptionDBEntities db = new SubscriptionDBEntities();
    var user = db.Subscriptions.Find(id);
    if (TryUpdateModel(user))
    {
        user.Status = "Y";
        db.SaveChanges();                
    }
    return View("Index");
}
```

It ends up giving me an Exception.

I am pretty new to MVC/coding so I apologize if this question is lame

Comment: So what's the issue with what you have now?

Comment: I just wrote this method in my MVC controller
 ``` 
//public ActionResult Edit(Subscription sub)
        //{
        //    sub.Status = "Y";
        //    return View("index");
        //}
```
and it gives me a NullReference exception

Comment: does the view from where you call the Edit action contains a form that map your Subscription object?

Comment: Show the code in your view